# Is there a css selector for punctuation or character?

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-face

Given the element :

```
<span>一、對話 Dialogues</span>
```

One of my font is really unelegant on that side, adding an overly wide space :
[image]

**Is there a css rule to style only the punctuation `、` ?**

NB: I searched the web and found nothing. Currently assume only HTML elements can receive styles. So I have to use JS to get the string, then `str.replace('、','<span class="punt">、</span>')`, then put back the string with the dedicated html element and class. But I would like to ask the community and create this question, even if dumb, so other users may find this question/answer in the future.

Comment: You're right. You need to wrap the punctuation (or, more generally, anonymous inline element) in an HTML element, so that it has "hooks" that the CSS can latch onto.

Comment: Thank you. It's what I suspected but worth checking. : )

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Font-face and [Unicode range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) to style your punctuation with an other font.

First, identify your characters' code :

```js
var charcode = '、'.codePointAt(0).toString(16); // "3001"
alert(charcode) // "3001"
```

Then, load your default font and your support font with unicode range

```css
/* For general characters  *********************************** */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Font1onPC'),       /* tries to load local font file */
       url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/font.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/font.woff') format('woff');
}
/* For special characters  ********************************** */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';     /* IMPORTANT: same name*/
  src: local('Font2onPC'),       /* tries to load local font file */
       url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/anotherFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/anotherFont.woff') format('woff');
  unicode-range: U+3001;     /* IMPORTANT */
}
```

Should work.

**Source :** https://jakearchibald.com/2017/combining-fonts/

Alternatively, you could edit that font on this character.

Comment: I documented above, but it didn't work for me on Chrome 89.